# JavaScript Class solution for Validate Binary Search Tree

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to use `Class` in JavaScript to solve this problem: Validate Binary Search Tree. If I use functions, it works fine, but with this code I always have the error (with LeetCode):

```sh
isValidBST is not a function
```

Here's the code:

```js
class Solution {
    constructor(root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    get result() {
        return this.helper(this.root, -Infinity, Infinity);
    }

    helper(root, low, high) {
        if (!root) return true;
        else {
            let val = root.val;
            if (val <= low || val >= high) return false;
            if (!this.helper(root.right, val, high)) return false;
            if (!this.helper(root.left, low, val)) return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
var isValidBST = new Solution(root);
isValidBST.result();
```

I'm quite confused. I've tried:

```js
isValidBST.result();
isValidBST.result;
console.log(isValidBST.result);
```

Comment: This error does not make sense to come from this code. Are you sure it's not something else trying to call `isValidBST()`?

Comment: Leetcode doesn't offer a class boilerplate for this--just fill out the `isValidBST` function.

Comment: @VLAZ: I'm pretty sure. Unless LeetCode does something else under the hood. I pasted the whole code.

Comment: @ggorlen You can't call `this` outside of a function.

Comment: "*I'm trying to use `class` in JavaScript to solve this problem*" - don't. A `class` is not necessary here.

Comment: @Bergi I understand that I don't "have to" use Class here, I'm just trying to use OOP with Javascript.

Comment: @Viet What exactly is the LeetCode task? Does it say something like "*Write a function `isValidBst` …*"? Then of course it would try to call it.

Comment: @Viet Does it not? IIRC LeetCode is one of those coding challenge sites. They usually give you some sandbox to write code in but then take that code and execute it against unit tests. And if the unit tests are doing something like `actualOutput = isValidBST(input); assertThat(actualOutput, expectedOutput)` then you're not really in charge.

Comment: @Viet Yes, you should do OOP. But you should use OOP without classes. At least for this task, where they are not just unncessary but rather inappropriate.

Comment: There are plenty of Leetcode problems where writing classes actually makes sense because they are stateful. See https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-search-tree-iterator/ for example to practice your JS OOP.

Comment: Assuming that [**this is the problem you're working on**](https://leetcode.com/problems/validate-binary-search-tree/), then Bergi is correct. When switching to JavaScript, the code indicates that you are to write a function named `isValidBST` that returns the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your answers. Now I understand the issue: LeetCode forces me to run the function `isValidBST` that takes the parameter `root` and return the result.
Doing so solves it:

```js
class Solution {
    constructor(root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    get result() {
        return this.helper(this.root, -Infinity, Infinity);
    }

    helper(root, low, high) {
        if (!root) return true;
        else {
            let val = root.val;
            if (val <= low || val >= high) return false;
            if (!this.helper(root.right, val, high)) return false;
            if (!this.helper(root.left, low, val)) return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}

var isValidBST = function(root) {
    const res = new Solution(root)
    return res.result;
};
```

I understand using Classes is kind of overkill but I'm trying to use Classes with Javascript anywhere I can to practice my OOP.